# Замена формулы на значение гугл таблицы

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Подскажите, есть ли возможность, заменить формулу на значение. А именно, имеется два числа, которые нужно перемножить (ячейка А1 и B1). Результат выводит в ячейку C1. но мне необходимо, чтобы при наведении на результат, светилась не формула, и значения. Сейчас светится так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно, чтобы при выделении, показывало вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы при копировании в другой документ у меня сохранялся не результат, а два числа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно записать в ячейку "=100*1.4" (почти так, как уже и сделано выше), тогда светиться будет то, что Вам нужно, и при копировании оба сомножителя останутся. Но если аргументы нужно связать с другими ячейками, то ссылки на эти ячейки обязательно останутся в формуле и будут "светиться" - заменить их числами в этом месте нет возможности.

Answer (score 2):

Заменить формулу всё таки можно, тоже искал на этот вопрос. Выделяем ячейки, копируем стандартной комбинацией CTRL+C, Затем вставляем комбинацией CTRL+SHIFT+V, вставляются числа. Также можно через вкладку "правка" > "специальная вставка" > выбрать "вставить только значения"